# Stacking multiple columns using pivot longer in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, spatial, tidyr

I am trying to change my data from wide to long on r using pivot_longer. There appear to be a few people having similar issues on here but I have been unable to adapt their solutions to my data. I have attached a picture of example data in the **wide data example** and what I am trying to achieve in the **long data example**.

In summary I have a time and reference column which refer to all columns, I also have multiple columns of group, subject, ID, xcoordinate ycoordinate in the form of:
group1, subject1. ID1, xcoord1 ycoord1, group2, subject2, ID2, xcoord2, ycoord2 and so on... What I want is a long table with columns:

time, reference, group, subject, ID, xcoord, ycoord.

With the 5 columns stacking their respective numbered columns, and the time and reference columns repeating for the relevant stacks.

```
 df %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = -c(time, reference),
names_to = c("group", "subject", "ID", "xcoord", "ycoord")
```

My understanding is that I require to use the names_pattern function, although I cant seem to get that to work, and I cant find anything clear describing How I should be using it. I should say my data is much wider than the example data, so can't really rely on numbering of columns.

appreciate any help

wide data example

```
    time reference group1 subject1 ID1 xcoord1 ycoord1 group2 subject2 ID2 xcoord2 ycoord2 group3 subject3 ID3 xcoord3 ycoord3
1  00:01   4097365      1        4   1    7.44   38.16      0       21   2   33.90   47.26      1       15   3   21.53    2.67
2  00:02   4097366      1        4   1    9.84   37.03      0       21   2   32.98   48.47      1       15   3   21.82    2.95
3  00:03   4097367      1        4   1   12.01   35.83      0       21   2   30.17   50.33      1       15   3   22.06    4.45
4  00:04   4097368      1        4   1   12.15   34.17      0       21   2   29.85   50.52      1       15   3   23.50    4.75
5  00:05   4097369      1        4   1   15.27   32.94      0       21   2   28.39   51.30      1       15   3   24.25    4.76
6  00:06   4097370      1        4   1   18.96   31.98      0       21   2   28.39   52.36      1       15   3   25.31    6.57
7  00:07   4097371      1        4   1   22.50   31.13      0       21   2   26.59   53.14      1       15   3   26.05    7.04
8  00:08   4097372      1        4   1   27.47   30.15      0       21   2   25.89   53.94      1       15   3   27.29    7.91
9  00:09   4097373      1        4   1   32.17   29.92      0       21   2   24.64   54.42      1       15   3   27.47    8.44
10 00:10   4097374      1        4   1   33.77   27.49      0       21   2   24.61   55.23      1       15   3   28.59    8.71
```

Long data example

```
   time reference group subject ID xcoord ycoord
1  00:01   4097365     1       4  1   7.44  38.16
2  00:01   4097365     0      21  2  33.90  47.26
3  00:01   4097365     1      15  3  21.53   2.67
4  00:02   4097366     1       4  1   9.84  37.03
5  00:02   4097367     0      21  2  32.98  48.47
6  00:02   4097368     1      15  3  21.82   2.95
7  00:03   4097369     1       4  1  12.01  35.83
8  00:03   4097370     0      21  2  30.17  50.33
9  00:03   4097371     1      15  3  22.06   4.45
10 00:04   4097372     1       4  1  12.15  34.17
```

edit: playing about a bit with the data I have managed to achieve this odd solution which is a mixture of long and wide data.

dput(head(df1))

```
structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), state = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Alive", "Alive;:", "Dead", "Dead;:"
), class = "factor"), reference = c("1880439", "1880439", "1880439", 
"1880439", "1880439", "1880439"), num = c("1", NA, "2", "3", 
"4", "5"), group = c("1", NA, "1", "4", "0", "0"), X = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ID = c(1L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), subect = c(21L, 
NA, 7L, -1L, 2L, 6L), x = c(3514L, NA, 2807L, 5550L, 3956L, 3686L
), y = c(-1644L, NA, -510L, 4400L, 1297L, -55L), speed = c("5.23", 
NA, "3.24", "0.00", "2.31", "3.57"), group1 = c("0", NA, "4", 
"1", "1", "0"), ID1 = c(13L, NA, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), subect1 = c(9L, 
NA, -1L, 13L, 14L, 11L), x1 = c(882L, NA, 5550L, 3004L, 761L, 
3317L), y1 = c(-1468L, NA, 4400L, 1633L, 559L, 1443L), speed1 = c("1.70", 
NA, "0.00", "3.06", "2.92", "3.30"), group2 = c("4", NA, "0", 
"1", "0", "0"), ID2 = c(24L, NA, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), subect2 = c(-1L, 
NA, 1L, 18L, 5L, 10L), x2 = c(5550L, NA, 5031L, 3936L, 3972L, 
3623L), y2 = c(4400L, NA, -74L, 190L, 686L, 356L), speed2 = c("0.00", 
NA, "0.54", "1.06", "0.95", "2.49"), speed.group2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)).
```

the dataframe the code results in looks like this

```
> head(df1)
# A tibble: 6 x 24
   time state reference num   group X        ID subect     x     y speed group1   ID1 subect1    x1    y1 speed1 group2   ID2 subect2    x2    y2 speed2
  <dbl> <fct> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <lgl> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  <int>   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>  <int>   <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
1     0 Aliv~ 1880439   1     1     NA        1     21  3514 -1644 5.23  0         13       9   882 -1468 1.70   4         24      -1  5550  4400 0.00  
2     0 Aliv~ 1880439   NA    NA    NA       NA     NA    NA    NA NA    NA        NA      NA    NA    NA NA     NA        NA      NA    NA    NA NA    
3     0 Aliv~ 1880439   2     1     NA        2      7  2807  -510 3.24  4         14      -1  5550  4400 0.00   0         25       1  5031   -74 0.54  
4     0 Aliv~ 1880439   3     4     NA        4     -1  5550  4400 0.00  1         15      13  3004  1633 3.06   1         26      18  3936   190 1.06  
5     0 Aliv~ 1880439   4     0     NA        5      2  3956  1297 2.31  1         16      14   761   559 2.92   0         27       5  3972   686 0.95  
6     0 Aliv~ 1880439   5     0     NA        6      6  3686   -55 3.57  0         17      11  3317  1443 3.30   0         28      10  3623   356 2.49  
# ... with 1 more variable: speed.group2 <lgl>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Providing links to sample data is generally discouraged because it makes it difficult for people to work with the data, and there is a non-trivial risk involved in clicking unknown links.

Comment: sorry, that should be sorted now. still a relative novice so was a bit unsure how to do this initially but after thinking a bit it seems quite obvious now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would first rename columns and insert underscore right before number, then use that as separator in `pivot_longer`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rename_at(-c(1:2), ~ str_replace(., "(\\w+)(\\d)", "\\1_\\2")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(1:2), names_to = c(".value", "num"), names_sep = "_")
```

**Edit** (2/7/20):

With your updated dataset, it appears that some of the variable column names don't have a number at the end. We can add `0` for those.

Also, I assume you want: `group`, `ID`, `subect`, `x`, `y`, `speed` that are repeated (with the first `group` in column 5 separated from its related variables in columns 7-11).

```
df1 %>%
  rename_at(c(5,7:11), ~ paste0(., "0")) %>%
  rename_at(-c(1:4, 6, 24), ~ str_replace(., "(\\w+)(\\d+)", "\\1_\\2")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(1:4, 6, 24), names_to = c(".value", "val"), names_sep = "_")
```

**Output** (Revised):

```
# A tibble: 18 x 13
    time state   reference num   X     speed.group2 val   group    ID subect     x     y speed
   <dbl> <fct>   <chr>     <chr> <lgl> <lgl>        <chr> <chr> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1     0 Alive;: 1880439   1     NA    NA           0     1         1     21  3514 -1644 5.23 
 2     0 Alive;: 1880439   1     NA    NA           1     0        13      9   882 -1468 1.70 
 3     0 Alive;: 1880439   1     NA    NA           2     4        24     -1  5550  4400 0.00 
 4     0 Alive;: 1880439   NA    NA    NA           0     NA       NA     NA    NA    NA NA   
 5     0 Alive;: 1880439   NA    NA    NA           1     NA       NA     NA    NA    NA NA   
 6     0 Alive;: 1880439   NA    NA    NA           2     NA       NA     NA    NA    NA NA   
 7     0 Alive;: 1880439   2     NA    NA           0     1         2      7  2807  -510 3.24 
 8     0 Alive;: 1880439   2     NA    NA           1     4        14     -1  5550  4400 0.00 
 9     0 Alive;: 1880439   2     NA    NA           2     0        25      1  5031   -74 0.54 
10     0 Alive;: 1880439   3     NA    NA           0     4         4     -1  5550  4400 0.00 
11     0 Alive;: 1880439   3     NA    NA           1     1        15     13  3004  1633 3.06 
12     0 Alive;: 1880439   3     NA    NA           2     1        26     18  3936   190 1.06 
13     0 Alive;: 1880439   4     NA    NA           0     0         5      2  3956  1297 2.31 
14     0 Alive;: 1880439   4     NA    NA           1     1        16     14   761   559 2.92 
15     0 Alive;: 1880439   4     NA    NA           2     0        27      5  3972   686 0.95 
16     0 Alive;: 1880439   5     NA    NA           0     0         6      6  3686   -55 3.57 
17     0 Alive;: 1880439   5     NA    NA           1     0        17     11  3317  1443 3.30 
18     0 Alive;: 1880439   5     NA    NA           2     0        28     10  3623   356 2.49
```

Comment: thanks for the help however this isn't working on my full data set. the error I am receiving is:

Error: Expected a vector, not NULL
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 174 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].

Comment: Sorry to hear - can you share info on your full data set such as `dput(head(df))`? And edit the question above with the results of this? This would at least provide the first 6 rows of data and show the structure of your columns and names.

Comment: I have managed to play about with it a bit, however there appears to still be an error. There are three blocks or chunks which I have tried (unsuccessfully to reorganise this further, Ideally, I would still like a simpler solution

Comment: @Stavrum see edited answer, I hope this might be helpful. I'm happy to try again if this is closer to what you need.